# Change Code Signing of Project from command line

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, command

I made a script to copy,rename and change Bundle Id of a project from command line, after that process, my next step is to change the code signing of the project to point to the new certificates.

Is there any way of doing this from command line?

Edit: I just saw that that info is stored on the .pbxproj, how can I change that file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can re-sign a build using the following:

```
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=`xcode-select -print-path`/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
codesign -f -s "iPhone Developer" -vv Example.app/Example
```

If all you have is an IPA, just unzip it, it's a normal zip file with a single `Payload` directory containing your application.

**Edit:**

If you need to change an Xcode project itself, an Xcode project is just a bundle, change into the directory and open the `project.pbxproj` file.  You should be able to simply use `sed` to find and replace the developer identity.

There may be better options, such as supplying the setting on the command-line to `xcodebuild`.  If you give more background on what it is you are trying to do, you may get better suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, but that is for doing it after the build is done, I need to know how to do it as soon as I create the new project, what I need is to change the pbxproj

Comment: I finally found where it is, so what I need to do is just change the .pbxproj file to point to the new certificates, is "sed" good enough for this?

Comment: I managed to change the profile in the .pbxproj, but it changes in the Project, not in the Target!

Comment: Then you aren't changing existing settings, you're inserting a new setting at a different level.  `sed` probably won't be enough, you might have to parse the project file.  Again, what are you doing?  You're missing out some very important information.

Comment: What Im doing is create a new project from command line based on a previous one, I made a script that copies it, renames it and change the bundle id, all from command line, now I need to change the pbxproj from command line too to point to new certificates

Comment: Why are you cloning projects?